# How to use item from form:select outside the form? spring, hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have got an entity class with single publication and list of all existing publications. On jsp-edit page I have a list of this publication and i would like to show when user choose some publication's title (saved as publication_id to db) how many of this publication exist in db -> like $item.total but I would like to show this value dynamically after select of publication and outside the select form...

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:select path="publication" cssStyle="width : 350px;" >
                <option  value="" ></option>
                <c:forEach var="item" items="${publicationList}">
                    <c:if test="${item.id == publication.id}">
                        <option value="${item.id}" selected="selected" >${item.title}</option>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: why do you need `form:select` outside of the form, just use a plain html `select`

Comment: dont need select, but the value of selected item... And I want this value (${item.total}) to change dynamically whenever the user change selected option

Comment: In JSF you must have the form components inside a form, otherwise you will have an error. I guess in Spring is similar. Also as a suggestion you can check the tag file where is declared the form:form, form:select, etc.

Comment: Are you simply trying to re-display the selected option somewhere else on the page?

Comment: yes, exactly what Mostfoolish said... I tried to redosplay selected option, but no idea how to achieve this... Like Jessai said it only leads to an error ;f

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to do this. this is the simplest javascript example I could come up with (adjust as needed).

using jQuery:

the following will add a change event listener on the publication field.  the function will read the value of the publication field, and set it to the span 'someOtherField'.

```
$("#publication").change(function() {$("#someOtherField").html($("#publication").val())});
```

Comment: hah, js was my first thought but unfortunatelly it causes an error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null. As I've read somewhere it can be caused by other scripts which I am using on page load and I didnt have time to check how to change it. I was hoping to achieve my goal without using js :P
But thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sounds like the object you were attempting to retrieve was null.  My guess is you're attempting to call jQuery's .append() function, and that's failing because the object that was selected is null. Check your selector and make sure you're retrieving the appropriate jQuery object (which is different than regular dom objects).